# How do you replace unsupported html tags inside a switch statement in an SSRS expression

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have an SSRS textbox currently using the following expression:

```
=Switch
(
    First(Fields!MyAwesomeId.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset") = 0, First(Fields!MyAwesomeNonmessage.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset"),
    First(Fields!MyAwesomeId.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset") = 1, First(Fields!MyAwesomeMessage.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset")
)
```

with it's markup type set to HTML.

The MyAwesomeMessage and MyAwesomeNonmessage fields both contain html break tags which according microsoft, don't render as such.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645967.aspx

How might I replace all the break tags in the data fields MyAwesomeMessage and MyAwesomeNonmessage with the correct characters to cause a line break on the finished report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your `switch` expression in a `replace` that will swap out all the text you specify.

In your case this would probably look like this:

```
=Replace(Switch(
                First(Fields!MyAwesomeId.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset") = 0
               ,First(Fields!MyAwesomeNonmessage.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset")

               ,First(Fields!MyAwesomeId.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset") = 1
               ,First(Fields!MyAwesomeMessage.Value, "MyAwesomeDataset")
               )
        ,"<br>"
        ,vbcrlf
        )
```

Comment: Haha! I've tried all kinds of permutations of the replace INSIDE the switch statement, to no avail.
Two thumbs good, Thanks Dave.

Comment: @sanepete  No worries.  For your reference, you could have used `replace` within your `switch`, you would have just had to put one around each potential return path.  So in the expression above, two times instead of one.